# Move, rotate perspective camera with 4x4 matrix dynamically

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, augmented-reality, move

Dear beloved community,

I've been dealing with the same problem the last days, which is an update of the View Matrix (4x4) of my camera. It should be used to set the position through an AR-Scene in three.js.

The customized matrix contains values from the Direct Sparse Odometry which will be parsed as a string through the WebView's JavaScript-Interface and provides values of my current pose. Depending on my initial point, DSO starts tracking the room and camera position (let's ignore that to keep it simple), which should be synch'd with the perspective camera afterwards. 
Converting this string to a 4x4 Matrix works, but setting:

1. the matrixWorldInverse (ViewMatrix?) caused nothing (does not update, neither with any of the 'common' update functions)
2. projectionMatrix causes zooming in and out of the scene but does not provide any movement, rotation. As far as I concern, it is used for characteristics only?

Is there any other way to move, rotate the camera inside of a scene?

There are no changes if I use the Matrix.set() method or fromArray() and/or any other update function threejs offers.

Thank you very much!

```
   var renderer, scene, camera, box, geometry, material, poseMatrix;

   init();
   animate();
   render();

   function init() {
        // renderer
       renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
           canvas: document.getElementById("mCanvas"),
           alpha: true
       });
       renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);
       renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
       document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
       // scene
       scene = new THREE.Scene();

       // camera
       camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
           75,
           window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
           1,
           1000
       );

       scene.add(camera);

       scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(100));

       placeBox();
       initPose();

   }

   function render() {
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
   }

   function placeBox()
   {
   // Using a test object which needs to have an absolute  position in world coordinates
       geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(3, 5, 3 );
       material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xfece46, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 3.1});
       box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

       // depends on parent coordinates
       box.position.set(0, 0, -10);
       scene.add(box);
       }

   function animate() {
       setCurrentPose();
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
   }

   function initPose(){
       // Default value provided by DSO
       var mTmpPose = "1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1"; //initial point of DSO
       var mDefaultPose = mTmpPose.split(',');

       // DSO Standard Pose 4x4 Matrix
      camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
      camera.matrixWorldInverse.fromArray(mDefaultPose);

       camera.updateWorldMatrix();

     //camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); <- does not work
    //camera.updateMatrix(); <- same issue

   }
   function setCurrentPose(){

   //Provides a string with current pose values
       var tmp = Android.getCurrentPose(); // example: 0.8953773, 0.39648485, 0.20272951, 0.0,
                                           //         -0.3792577, 0.44037524, 0.81377715, 0.0,
                                           //           0.23337325,-0.8055243, 0.5446719, 0.0,
                                           // .          -2.5238492, 13.470952, 0.715593, 1.0
       var pose = tmp[0].split(',');

       camera.matrixWorldInverse.fromArray(pose);
   // camera.projectionMatrix.fromArray(pose);

       camera.updateWorldMatrix();
    //   camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); <- does not work
   // camera.updateMatrix(); <- same issue
   }
```

Comment: I updated my response with a possible work around for your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Augmented Reality no way to set the camera matrix *(as you could in VR)* because in AR the camera position is controlled by the user. This not unique to Aframe/Three.js, and is the same across all major Augmented Reality frameworks.

Generally, the scene's origin and the camera's initial position are the same, this makes it easier for the framework to place content relative to the origin (camera's starting position).

Once the scene's origin is established the camera is free to move through the scene at the user's discretion, so you can't force the camera to look in a certain direction because the render engine does not have that control.

**[update]**

If you are trying to force the user to focus on specific content in the scene, then you can try moving the scene content so that it's directly in the user's view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. I really appreciate it! Sadly, I have to use an absolute position of the box, because the user should be able to scan the object inside this bounding box.